# I set position as absolute for div with id, and set it's top, left and others in terms of % (also relative to parent), how do those % convert to px?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Given is my code snippet, both the HTML and the CSS files.

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Picasso Painting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./new.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="back-wall"></div>
    <div class="characters">
        <div id="offwhite-character">
            <div id="white-hat"></div>
            <div id="black-mask">
                <div class="eyes left"></div>
                <div class="eyes right"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="gray-instrument">
                <div class="black-dot"></div>
                <div class="black-dot"></div>
                <div class="black-dot"></div>
                <div class="black-dot"></div>
                <div class="black-dot"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="tan-table"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

new.css stylesheet:

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(184, 132, 46);
}

#back-wall {
    background-color: #8B4513;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#offwhite-character {
    width: 300px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: GhostWhite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 17.5%;
}
```

In the div with the id offwhite-character, I have set it's position as absolute so that I can set it's top and bottom, which I have set in terms of % unit. So, now it doesn't have any non-static positioned ancestor, so I presume it will be relative to , correct me if I am wrong?

But, then in the firefox development tools, when I inspect element, I don't see any calculated values for html element. So those top: 20% and left: 17.5%, these are evaluated on what basis? Like 20% of what? 17.5% of what value?

The values that firefox inspect element tool show are:
[image: These are the top and left values computed by firefox browser].

So, now I am clueless as to how these are computed and in general regarding the % unit as well. Can someone help me out with this?

I wasn't particularly trying to achieve anything.

I just presumed (as per my understanding so far) that when we say evaluated relative to parent element for relative units, we take their parent's values (like top, left, and other values) as the reference and then take its 20% or 2em or 1rem, etc.

Like here, what I think:
top: 20% ==> top: 20% of parent's (some unit value, idk whether it's top, or width or what)??

Comment: The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. The element is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor (if any) or to the initial containing block. See: [CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: What I want to ask is that no matter what relative unit we use, it ultimately comes down to px unit in the end and I want to know how to convert them? Eg: I set top: 20%; so how will it convert to px, if it has no non-static ancestor?

Comment: The browser window, or iframe, is the "initial containing block" for an absolute positioned element without a positioned ancestor. So if the browser window is 800px high, and you use `top: 20%;` the top of the element will start at 160px down. So it's not the HTML page size, or the body size.

Comment: Makes a lot sense now, thank you so much